# Testing a Computational Topology Algorithm

Tags: discussion

I have a algorithm in Computational Topology that I wish other computer scientists to test. Can I post it on the main site? I don't have that many contacts in computational topology.

Comment: Well, it depends on the algorithms and the kinds of tests. I would recommend going through the help center to help you decide.

Comment: more info in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9446/2015/7/15). alas se is kind of like jeopardy, everything has to be stated in the form of a question. maybe some way to format it like that? eg ask for refs? there are not a huge number of "contacts in comp topology" in all of se anyway! alas, while worthwhile/ "open" research, think there will be little or negative response...

Comment: I don't think it would be suitable question. I would suggest using Google+ and asking people like David or Jeff or Suresh to help your post reach more people in CG. Also there is a mailing list for GC conference IIRC which you can try.

Comment: Ok thanks kaveh

Comment: Just saw this. I don't think the main site is the right way to go, but if you were to ping me directly or via G+ I'd be happy to spread the word.

Comment: @SureshVenkat According to google plus I can't ping you directly because I am not in your Circles. Can you add me on google plus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to all the comments I should ask Venkat about this. Thanks everyone for all your help.